# How can a class be an array and an object at the same time?

Tags: php

Reading this [documentation of the Silex PHP micro-framework](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html),

In the section

> The service will now be registered in the application, and the convert method will be used as 
>   converter:

The code

```
$app['converter.user'] = $app->share(function () {
    return new UserConverter();
});

$app->get('/user/{user}', function (User $user) {
    // ...
})->convert('user', 'converter.user:convert');
```

`$app` is an array + an object at the same time. Or let's say it starts as an array but gets assigned an object. This confuses me: `$app['converter.user'] =`.

How does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the PHP [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface, as well as the [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface will allow PHP to know that your class can be treated as an array. One easy way to do this would be to extend from the [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class.

Essentially, what's happening with these interfaces is that you have a private variable, and methods on how to access that variable. The interfaces let PHP know that these methods exist, and that it can in fact treat the class as an array.

Now, if Silex uses this method or not, I can't comment. However, that is how you would create a PHP class that can also be accessed as an array

Comment: @DanFromGermany it smore like `$app->offSetGet("converter.user")`

Comment: After reading about `ArrayAccess` everything got clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$app` is not an array and an object. It is just an object, of which you can access the values through either the index or using the `->` operator.

To answer your 2nd question, this is possible through overloading, which you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).